# How to configure an Apple keyboard on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout

Boot Camp doesn't seem to work. Besides the zip file is around 800 MB size.
There is loads of info in the web, but nothing really efficient.

Where can I find a little tiny user-friendly Apple keyboard driver file for Windows 8.1?

I run the file **AppleKeyboardInstaller64.exe** from Boot Camp (v. 5.1.5621), but the software says it didn't install anything

[image]

Comment: What version of Boot Camp do you claim does not work because the current version has full support for Windows 8.1

Comment: The last one: 5.1.5621 got from here: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US
I run then the file BootCamp\Drivers\Apple\AppleKeyboardInstaller64

Comment: By the way, I have a Portuguease Apple keyboard

Comment: You are running Windows 8.1 with the current boot camp and you have a problem? [Strange](http://superuser.com/questions/336314/apple-uk-british-english-keyboard-key-mapping?rq=1) you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: I cannot run the setup file because it says it's not for my device, but I can run the keyboard driver file. Though it says it didn't install the driver because the current one is more recent.